# How is this equation a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Take $f(x) = 4-x^2$
and let $f:(-2,2) \rightarrow (0,4)$

Q: is this a function? if no change codomain so it becomes a function that is onto.

I got: 
\begin{align}
f(-2) &= 0\\
f(-1) &= 3\\
f(0) &= 4\\
f(1) &= 3\\
f(2) &= 0\\
\end{align}

Here we see clearly its not a function since we have $f(2)$ and $f(-2)=0$, and $f(-1)$ and $f(1) = 3$
and we can see that $f(0)$ is not mapped so we can change the codomain to $(0,4]$ 
but I am still not sure about $f(-1)$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @amd I believe these are not ordered pairs, but intervals in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note that it is ok for a function to have 2 $x$'s that give the same $y$ ($f(x_1)=f(x_2)$) but we say that an expression is not a function if it maps the same $x$(pre-image) to 2 different $y$'s (images) (i.e.$f(x)=y_1$ and $f(x)=y_2$ with $y_1 \ne y_2$)

Comment: But for this function to be bijective you need to take the positive part only of the domain(or only the negative part) to have the function being strictly monotonic

Comment: Your comment that $f(2) = f(-2)$ only means that the function is not injective (one-to-one). But it is still a function.

Comment: But $2$ and $-2$ are not in the domain $(-2,2)$, so it's not a problem that $f(2)$ and $f(-2)$ are not in the range. So it's enough to change the codomain to $(0,4]$. I don't understand your problem with $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$.

Comment: @FareedAF can you give me an example where an f(x) =y1 and f(x) = y2?

Comment: @ZAX9732 An example would be $\pm \sqrt{x}$. For $x=4$ this could equal $2$ or $-2$. However, whatever this thing is, it is not a function. The whole point of a function is that it cannot map one element of the domain to more than one element in the codomain. So, there is no such example of a function where $f(x) = y_1$ and $f(x) = y_2$, with $y_1 \neq y_2$, because it contradicts the very definition of a function.

Comment: but its possible to make a function by changing the domain or co domain? to only include positve numbers right?

Comment: for example changing the codomain to include only positive numbers? or is it changing the codomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a function, because $f(x)$ is defined for all $x \in (-2,2)$ and each element of the domain maps to only one element in the codomain. $f(-2)$ and $f(2)$ are in fact not in the domain of the function, and so are not defined, but even if they *did* both map to $0$ this would not contradict $f$ being a function—it would simply mean that the function is not one-to-one. Indeed, $f(-1) = f(1)$, but this doesn’t mean $f$ isn’t a function.

Also, there is no problem with elements in the codomain not being mapped to. It is still a function!

One-to-one means: for all elements $y$ in the codomain, there is at *most* one element $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y$.

Being a function means: for all elements $x$ in the domain, there is exactly one element $y$ in the codomain such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: so if i have f(1) = 2 and f(-1) = 2 that will mean its not one to one since two X maps to one Y right?

Comment: @ZAX9732 Correct.